# When did independent Mexico start trading with Asia?

Tags: trade, mexico, age-of-sail, asia, ocean

Throughout the 17th and 18th century Spanish galleons shipped Chinese goods from Manila to Acapulco. After Mexican independence, Spain retained the Philippines and the galleons no longer crossed the Pacific.

The designated Committee for the Development of California recommended the creation of an "Asiatic-Mexican Company" to trade across similar Pacific routes [Reynolds: *Principal Actions of the California Junta de Fomento*]. The Committee represented that only a government monopoly would be able to invest enough, and bear enough risk, to trade across the Pacific Ocean. The Company was never founded, but transoceanic trade with Peru and Hawaii did happen regularly in the 1820s and 1830s.

When did the Mexican state or Mexican companies begin direct trade with Asian countries?